# How to import large data set from MongoDb to S3 in the form of JSON? (using Node.JS in server side)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amazon-s3, large-data

I am trying to import Large data by using mongo find query using pagination. There are total 2.2M records. If the document per page are low than it will take a lot of time but if I increase the document per page like(50k-100K) then MongoDb connection get exhuast.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. You're trying to import the MongoDB to an S3 bucket and asking about the best way to do it? If yes, why are you trying to save a database on a bucket? For backups?

Comment: @DavidHarvey I am not saving database. I just want some records from one collection(around 2.2M records) and convert them JSON and send that file(2.5GB) to S3 for Quicksight analysis. I want the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you dead set on Quicksight for analysis? There are other tools that can run off of the mongoDB directly rather than exporting the data to an s3 bucket

Comment: @DavidHarvey could you please suggest other tools to get data directly from mongoDB.